# Identify on which Contract was a WCF service called

Tags: c#, wcf

Is possible to know which contract has been called in a multiple contract service? In this, case, in the constructor.

The implementing class of the service is like this:

```cs
public class Service : IContract1, IContract2
{
    public Service()
    {
        //Identify if constructor was called from IContract1 or IContract2
    }
}
```

Comment: nothing is "called" from an interface, an interface just defines a contract that the implementing class must follow. It doesnt even explicitly *need* a constructor at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to implement is a [WCF Message Inspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047(v=vs.110).aspx). A MessageInspector is a "message filter" that can intercept and inspect the messages coming in or going out of the service layer infrastructure.

On the server, you would implement the [IDispatchMessageInspector Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here is a pretty good example:

http://www.aspnet4you.com/wcf/index.php/2013/01/30/message-interception-auditing-and-logging-at-wcf-pipeline/